# Why can I run globally installed node modules by name?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I install a node module globally, let's say the `grunt` module. I install it by:

`npm install -g grunt`

It's installed in `%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\grunt`.

Then I can run it in command line, like `grunt --version`. How does this happen? I mean, why can I directly use `grunt` as a command?

BTW, I'm using Windows. And I install NodeJS by `.msi` installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't really running the `grunt` package as a whole from the command.

The setup for this starts in [`grunt`'s `package.json`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/package.json). In that, it's [specified a `bin` script](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) that's named the same as the package.

```
"bin": {
  "grunt": "bin/grunt"
},
```

When you [install the package globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders), npm adds an executable file for each `bin` script (there can be multiple per package) to a directory in your system's PATH, allowing a command line to find them when you type the command.

When you run `grunt`, it's sort of a shortcut to running `node bin/grunt` from the directory where it's installed, passing along any arguments you provided after it.

Comment: I see, there is a `grunt.cmd` in  `%APPDATA%\npm`, which has been added to system path. So when I type `grunt` in command line, this batch file will be called.